# update datefield - mysql not working

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what is the wrong with the query?

```
UPDATE user_package
SET project_applications = '5'
AND refresh_date = '2016-04-26'
WHERE   package_id = '12'
AND refresh_date = '2016-03-27';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `AND` by Comma (`,`)

Try this:

```
UPDATE user_package
SET project_applications = '5',
 refresh_date = '2016-04-26'
WHERE   package_id = '12'
AND refresh_date = '2016-03-27';
```